# Search the directories with modified date of today

Tags: batch-file

I have just started to learn how to code in batch file. I would appreciate help with the following requirement for my batch file.

I have do some research and found this link ([Is there a file in a directory with a modified date of today - Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440612/is-there-a-file-in-a-directory-with-a-modified-date-of-today-batch-file)) somehow similar to what i want.

```
Are there files in a directory with a modified date of today

If yes (may have more than one file with the modified date of today)
   Copy the files into the folder
else
   echo no file found

else
NO file for today
```

I try the solution in the link, but that solution only managed to return one file. For instance, there are two files namely test_20150114 and testString_20150114, the solution will only copy the file testString_20150114 to the folder. I want to copy files test_20150114 and testString_20150114 into the folder. How can i achieve it?

I try using two for loop to achieve but somehow fail.

Here the code i grab from another website with quite similar requirement as mine,

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%I in ("%date%") do set today=%%I
for /f "tokens=5" %%H in ('dir /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "%~nx0$" ^| find "test"') do (
for /f "tokens=4*" %%H in ('dir /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "%~nx0$" ^| find "%today%"') do (

rem record success for later
set found=1

rem search file %%I for "test" (case-insensitive).
find /i "string" "%%I">NUL 

rem Was last command successful?
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    echo test Files Found for today
If %%H GTR 0 (
  echo Found %%I file is greater than 0kb 
)
) else (
    echo test string NOT found
)
)
)
for /f "tokens=5" %%H in ('dir /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "%~nx0$" ^| find "testString"')do(

for /f "tokens=4*" %%H in ('dir /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "%~nx0$" ^| find "%today%"') do (

rem record success for later
set found=1

rem search file %%I for "testString" (case-insensitive).
find /i "string" "%%I">NUL 

rem Was last command successful?
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    echo testString Files Found for today
If %%H GTR 0 (
  echo Found %%I file is greater than 0kb 

)
) else (
    echo test string NOT found
)
)
)
```

*EDIT: I manage to get this solution from the help of Serenity

```
  forfiles /s /m  *.* /d 0 /c "cmd /c 
  if @fsize==0 Echo @file is 0Kb || Copy @file D:\Test
```

Add on questions: After managed to find the files with date of today, i want to copy the content of the file to the new file. (Test.txt content will be copy to Result.txt)

Comment: Could you include your actual not working code?

Answer (score 0):

```
forfiles /d 0
```

list files modified today.

```
 Forfiles /d 0 && Echo copy etc || Echo File Not Found
```

Although ForFiles can execute it's own commands on found files and prints it's own message File Not Found.

```
forfiles /d 0 /p c:\windows /m *.ini /s /c "cmd /c copy ^"@path^" c:\somewhereelse\"
```

**Edit: Added cmd /c to command line**

Comment: thank for the answer. Beside searching for files that have today date, i also want to check if the file is greater than 0KB, how can i achieve that?

Comment: `forfiles /d 0 /c "cmd /c if @fsize==0 echo hi`

Comment: If you try to copy a zero byte file it will be deleted. That's what `Copy` does.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. In the end my query become like that: forfiles /s /m  *.* /d 0 /c "cmd /c copy @file D:\Test\". Since u mention that copy a zero byte file will be deleted, but the output is that it did copy zero byte file to the folder. Another thing is i want to be able to copy the content of the file to the new file. For instance, we found test_20150114 to have content of "test". I want to copy the content of "test" to the new file name Sales.txt. Am i able to do it?

Comment: A copy copies the whole file including the contents. Can you explain further? I can confirm copy no longer obeys older rules, and neither does DOS 5.5 (the version in Windows) unlike DOS 6.22.

Comment: I want to copy the content of the file to another file. For instance i have two files namely test.txt and test1.txt. I want to copy the content of the file from test.txt -> result.txt and test1.txt->result1.txt

Comment: You just do two copies. `copy file1.txt file2.txt` copies the file including contents. What am I missing in your question?

Comment: forfiles /s /m  *.* /d 0 /c "cmd /c if @fsize GTR 0 copy file1.txt file2.txt D:\Test\Result1.txt D:\Test\Result2.txt?? I want to change the filename when copy the file from one folder to another.

Comment: You have to do the copy command twice. Forfiles will call the copy command twice. So just taking the `/c` part (as the rest is working incl your if) do `/c "cmd /c copy @file c:\somewhere\@fname.txt"`. Type `forfiles /?` for help.